# are we able to getposition while vision.VideoPlayer is running?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, video-processing, matlab-cvst

In Matlab, I need to manually select object from `vision.VideoPlayer` directly while it is running. instead of show frame and then use `figure; imshow(frame); objectRegion=round(getPosition(imrect))`

are we able to do this?

Comment: Could you please clarify?  Are you trying to select an object without displaying the frame?  Or are did you mean `vision.VideoPlayer`, rather than `vision.VideoFileReader`?

Comment: I mean that while the videoPlayer is viewing the video frames, by using step function, can we select object from these frames ?

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately, you cannot. You would have to use `imshow` to display the image, to be able to use imrect.